# Remove islands from mainland coastline using a multipolygon Shapefile - GeoPandas

Tags: python, geopandas, shapefile

I want to remove all disconnected islands from the Australian coastline. I've imported the country as a Shapefile and can remove regions using a hard-coded boundary. But it would be inefficient to trace around the entire coastline to remove all disconnected islands. Is there quicker method using GeoPandas?

```
import geoplot as gplt
import geopandas as gpd

Oz = gpd.read_file('OZ.shp')

#polygon = Polygon([(140, -40), (150, -40), (150, -45), (140,-45)])
#Oz_clip = gpd.clip(Oz, polygon)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- have used geometry from here: https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files
- this contains a multipolygon made up of 6624 polygons
- have expanded out the multipolygon to polygons then created a **geodataframe** including the area of each polygon
- you can now take appoach of filtering by largest area polygons `head()` or polygons with area over a threshold

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(
    "https://www.abs.gov.au/statistics/standards/australian-statistical-geography-standard-asgs-edition-3/jul2021-jun2026/access-and-downloads/digital-boundary-files/AUS_2021_AUST_SHP_GDA2020.zip"
)

# expand polygons and move to UTM geometry
polys = (
    gpd.GeoSeries(
        gdf.dropna()["geometry"].apply(lambda g: g.geoms).explode(), crs=gdf.crs
    )
    .to_crs(gdf.estimate_utm_crs())
    .simplify(100)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)

# now build geodataframe limited by biggest area polygons
gdfm = (
    gpd.GeoDataFrame(data={"area": polys.area / 10**6}, geometry=polys, crs=polys.crs)
    .sort_values("area", ascending=0)
    # .head(3) # only one tasmania will be excluded
    .loc[lambda d: d["area"].gt(5000)]  # filter by size of polygon
    .reset_index()
)

# visualise
gdfm.explore(height=300, width=500)
```

```
    index   area    geometry
0   6411    7.787225e+06    POLYGON ((1023611.393 5771135.050, 1021232.002...
1   6373    6.490288e+04    POLYGON ((1497821.632 5153803.332, 1498006.176...
2   554 5.826181e+03    POLYGON ((26191.908 8735865.816, 26640.856 873..
```

[image]

Comment: Nice @Rob Raymond.